# Unable to connect using SSH connector in Mule

Tags: java, ssh, mule

I installed the SSH connector in Mule Studio (3.5). 

This is my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:stdio="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio"
      xmlns:ssh="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssh" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
      xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
      xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.1"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio/current/mule-stdio.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssh http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ssh/1.2.1/mule-ssh.xsd">
      <ssh:config name="SSH" host="${servername}"
            port="22" timeout="6000" callbackFlowName="callbackFlow" doc:name="SSH"
            shellMode="false" receiverBufferSize="1000" password="${password}"
            username="${user}">
            <ssh:connection-pooling-profile
                  initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ONE" exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW" />
      </ssh:config>
      <flow name="sshbiginsights-demoFlow1" doc:name="sshbiginsights-demoFlow1">
            <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
                  host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" />
            <ssh:send config-ref="SSH" content="pwd" doc:name="SSH"
                  breakLine="true" />
      </flow>
      <flow name="callbackFlow" doc:name="callbackFlow">
            <logger message="#[payload]" />
      </flow>
</mule>
```

When I try run the flow I get the following exception in the log:

```
INFO  2014-05-05 11:57:50,410 [[sshbiginsights-demo].sshbiginsights-demoFlow1.stage1.02] net.schmizz.sshj.common.SecurityUtils: BouncyCastle registration succeeded
WARN  2014-05-05 11:57:50,489 [[sshbiginsights-demo].sshbiginsights-demoFlow1.stage1.02] net.schmizz.sshj.DefaultConfig: Disabling high-strength ciphers: cipher strengths apparently limited by JCE policy
INFO  2014-05-05 11:57:50,662 [[sshbiginsights-demo].sshbiginsights-demoFlow1.stage1.02] net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl: Client identity string: SSH-2.0-SSHJ_0_8_1_SNAPSHOT
INFO  2014-05-05 11:57:50,775 [[sshbiginsights-demo].sshbiginsights-demoFlow1.stage1.02] net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl: Server identity string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
ERROR 2014-05-05 11:57:51,260 [reader] net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl: Dying because - {}
net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: [HOST_KEY_NOT_VERIFIABLE] Could not verify `ssh-rsa` host key with fingerprint `38:a3:94:7c:a9:78:19:2a:39:b2:89:f2:d1:86:2e:6a` for `server_name` on port 22
      at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.KeyExchanger.verifyHost(KeyExchanger.java:195)
      at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.KeyExchanger.handle(KeyExchanger.java:346)
      at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.handle(TransportImpl.java:450)
      at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.decode(Decoder.java:100)
      at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.received(Decoder.java:168)
      at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader.run(Reader.java:44)
INFO  2014-05-05 11:57:51,262 [reader] net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl: Disconnected - HOST_KEY_NOT_VERIFIABLE
ERROR 2014-05-05 11:57:51,264 [[sshbiginsights-demo].sshbiginsights-demoFlow1.stage1.02] net.schmizz.concurrent.Promise: <<kex done>> woke to: net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: [HOST_KEY_NOT_VERIFIABLE] Could not verify `ssh-rsa` host key with fingerprint `38:a3:94:7c:a9:78:19:2a:39:b2:89:f2:d1:86:2e:6a` for `server_name` on port 22
ERROR 2014-05-05 11:57:51,267 [[sshbiginsights-demo].sshbiginsights-demoFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.retry.notifiers.ConnectNotifier: Failed to connect/reconnect: Work Descriptor. Root Exception was: Could not reach ssh server at server_name:22. Type: class org.mule.api.ConnectionException
ERROR 2014-05-05 11:57:51,271 [[sshbiginsights-demo].sshbiginsights-demoFlow1.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to invoke send. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Could not reach ssh server at server_name:22 (org.mule.api.ConnectionException)
  org.mule.modules.ssh.multiplexer.SshConnector:172 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/ConnectionException.html)
2. Failed to invoke send. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.modules.ssh.multiplexer.processors.SendMessageProcessor:139 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.ConnectionException: Could not reach ssh server at server_name:22
      at org.mule.modules.ssh.multiplexer.SshConnector.connect(SshConnector.java:172)
      at org.mule.modules.ssh.multiplexer.connectivity.SshConnectorConnectionFactory.makeObject(SshConnectorConnectionFactory.java:52)
      at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1179)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

I saw the connector's code, that it's using net.schmizz.sshj library. I wrote the following in a java main -

```
SSHClient client = new SSHClient();
// client.addHostKeyVerifier("38:a3:94:7c:a9:78:19:2a:39:b2:89:f2:d1:86:2e:6a");
client.connect("server", 22);
client.authPassword("user", "password");
Session session = client.startSession();
Command cmd = null;
cmd = session.exec("pwd");
System.out.println(IOUtils.readFully(cmd.getInputStream()).toString());
cmd.close();
client.disconnect();
client.close();
```

When the addHostKeyVerifier is commented out I get the same exception. When I uncomment it it works. 

However, I don't see in the SSH connector where I can add this host key verifier.

Why am I getting this exception? Is it something to do with the server I'm trying to connect to? 

Thanks, 

Adi

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the SSH connector does not allow adding an individual host key verifier but it does load the list of known hosts:

https://github.com/mulesoft/sshmultiplexed-connector/blob/mule-module-SshMultiplexer-1.2.1/src/main/java/org/mule/modules/ssh/multiplexer/SshConnector.java#L158

from the default locations:

- `~/.ssh/known_hosts`
- `~/.ssh/known_hosts2`

Have you tried adding this host signature in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by replacing it? Replacing it with the '38:a3:94:7c:a9:78:19:2a:39:b2:89:f2:d1:86:2e:6a'?
Right now I have server_name,ip ssh-rsa bunch_of_characters

Comment: I said "placing" but I should have said "adding". Fixed. So, yes, is this host you're trying to connect added in `known_hosts`?